# Raku generic code to test if modules load

Tags: testing, module, raku

This is a generic code code in **/t** to test if .rakumod modules in **/lib** load.

```
use lib $*PROGRAM.sibling('../lib');
use Test;

my @dir = dir($*PROGRAM.sibling('../lib'), test => { $_ ~~ /.*rakumod/  } );
plan @dir.elems;

sub module( IO $dir ) {
  $dir.basename.Str ~~ /(\w+)\.rakumod/;
  return $0.Str;
}

for  @dir.map(&module) -> $module {
  use-ok $module, "This module loads: $module";
}
```

Before going any further (recursively looking at lib sub-folders ), I wonder in this is the right approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are testing a well-formed distribution then you should be using:

```
use lib $*PROGRAM.parent(2);
```

By pointing `use lib` at the directory containing your META6.json instead of the `lib` directory you help ensure that the provides entry of the META6.json file is up to date (since files not listed in the META6.json but that *do* exist inside `lib` won't be seen).

(*I'd even take it one step further and say don't use `use lib '...'` at all, and instead run your tests using `raku -I ...`. For instance -- what if you want to run these tests (for whatever reason) on the installed copy of some distribution?*)

With that said you could skip the directory recursion by using the META6 data. One method would be to read the META6.json directly, but a better way of doing so would be to get the module names from the distribution itself:

```
# file: zef/t/my-test.t
# cwd: zef/

use lib $*PROGRAM.parent(2); # or better: raku -I. t/my-test.t
use Test;

my $known-module = CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(short-name => "Zef");
my $comp-unit    = $*REPO.resolve($known-module);
my @module-names = $comp-unit.distribution.meta<provides>.keys;

use-ok($_) for @module-names;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It frames module writing in the context of module distribution, something I was not considering. Start working on it. Cheers!

Comment: The META6 distribution has benefit from your useful suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using @ugexe feedback and [META6 distribution](https://github.com/jonathanstowe/META6), the following code in **t/** tests that modules defined in META6.json load.

```
use META6;
use Test;

my $m = META6.new( file => $*PROGRAM.sibling('../META6.json') );
my @modules = $m<provides>.keys;
plan @modules.elems; 

for $m<provides>.keys -> $module {
  use-ok $module, "This module loads: $module";
}
```

This test has been pulled into the [META6 distribution](https://github.com/jonathanstowe/META6/pull/16).